# Pascal Simple Types

Tags: pascal

In Standard Pascal what are considered simple types? Are these the only types that can be returned from a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[according to the spec](http://www.moorecad.com/standardpascal/iso7185.html#6.4.2%20Simple-types), simple types are integer, real, Boolean, char, enumerated (`(red, yellow, green, blue, tartan)`), and subrange (`1..100`). [also according to the spec](http://www.moorecad.com/standardpascal/iso7185.html#6.6.2%20Function-declarations), functions can return only `simple-type-identifier` or (`|`) `pointer-type-identifier`.

Answer (score 0):

simple types in pascal,

**integer** for numeric,

**real** for floating point,

**char** for character,

**boolean** for the truth value, and

**string** for text

this is the basic types can use in pascal, and all of them can be return from function